# Flutter: Disable all hover effects for better performance

Tags: flutter, performance

I want to technically and fully disable any `hover`-effect in Flutter (desktop/windows).
When hovering over an `ElevatedButton`, a `hover`-effect starts.
This effect is undesired for our project, so I already changed the `MaterialState`-properties to set it only changes when disabled, not when hovered, which works fine:

```dart
MaterialStateProperty<Color?>? colorResolver(Color withColor, {Color? disabledColor}) =>
    MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>((states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
        return withColor;
      }
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
        return disabledColor ?? withColor.withOpacity(0.5);
      }
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
        return withColor;
      }
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.error)) {
        return withColor;
      }
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.focused)) {
        return withColor;
      }
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.dragged)) {
        return withColor;
      }
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.scrolledUnder)) {
        return withColor;
      }
      return withColor;
    });
```

However, when looking at the `toggleRepaintRainbow`, I can still see repaint operations, marked with the rainbow boxes around the ElevatedButtons.

How can I fully disable the hover effect, so that it will not trigger any rebuild?

[image: ElevatedButton gets marked in toggleRepaintRainbow]

Comment: it seems like rebuilds are not for the hover but for value changes, but you should provide more code.

Comment: @Benyamin why does it "seem" that way? Can you elaborate? The rainbow boxes clearly show the path of my mouse movement.